# Экс-главврач больницы чем отличается от экс главврача больницы?

Tags: орфография

Экс главврач больницы. Правильно в данном случае писать всё раздельно?
Ответ справочной службы русского языка
Этот случай неоднозначный (в отличие от сочетания экс главный редактор).
Здесь можно найти аргументы в пользу как раздельного, так и дефисного написания. По "правилу координации", недопустимо слитное или дефисное написание с приставкой или первой частью сложного слова, если вторая часть содержит пробел, то есть представляет собой сочетание слов. Таким образом, если приставка экс относится к сочетанию слов главврач больницы, то следует писать раздельно: экс главврач больницы.
С другой стороны, приставка экс может относиться к одному слову главврач, и тогда следует писать через дефис: экс-главврач больницы.

Я не пойму, какое смысловое различие в сочетаниях *экс главврач больницы* и *экс-главврач больницы?*

*Экс главврач больницы* - это бывший главврач больницы, а *экс-главврач больницы* - это кто?

В то же время Грамота пишет, что надо писать всегда *экс министр обороны*.

Answer (score 4):

~1. Если вы имеете в виду ответы грамотной "Справки", то их бесполезно сопоставлять. Там штука очень простая. На один вопрос, как правило, отвечает один человек, каждый раз разный. Даже обладая достаточной квалификацией (что тоже не всегда так), такая группа не в состоянии давать однозначные и однородные ответы на все вопросы, выходящие за рамки повседневной надобности. Хотя иногда дело просто в неудачности формулировок, которые приходится изобретать "на ходу".

~2. Разницы **в значении** нет никакой, тут я в корне не согласен с Людмилой и "Справкой". Даже если бывший главврач стал главврачом другой больницы (или там санатория - где еще главврачи бывают?), он не перестаёт быть бывшим по отношению к той больнице, про которую идет речь. Другими словами, для обоснования разницы приходится изобретать совершенно умозрительный, ирреальный контекст. Кстати, такой ирреальностью, оторванностью от действительности "Справка" всегда грешила.

~3. Вы совершенно верно пишете, что "главврач больницы" и "министр обороны" - вполне сопоставимые понятия одного грамматического поля, подход к ним должен быть аналогичным. Единственное, что может вызвать сомнения, это то, что "министр" - глава уникального ведомства, а больниц у нас много. Но я не вижу, как это может сказаться конкретно на выборе орфографии.

~4. Я за дефис. Понимаете, идя по пути запрещения дефиса при "должностях с пробелом", мы рискуем отменить его вовсе. Формально не существует должности "главврач", "министр", "капитан", "директор" или, там, "тренер". Все они руководители той или иной организации. И что теперь, всех бывших писать раздельно? Зачем тогда вообще правило с этим "экс"? А если не всех, то где граница? Я её совершенно не улавливаю ни из справкиного объяснения, ни из людмилиного. Аналогичная ситуация с "приставкой" "вице-", "лейб-", "фельд-" (в тех случаях, когда она пишется не слитно) и некоторыми другими.

~5. В чем "Справка" права. Ситуация неоднозначности - и, как следствие, стремления развести написания - действительно возможна. Но не в нашем случае, а в оригинальных "фигурах речи" типа "экс легитимный президент". Реально такие вещи возникают только от чрезмерного стремления украсить текст. В сочетании **с точным названием** должности такого быть не должно.

Answer (score 3):

Смыслового различия на первый взгляд  нет, всё тот же бывший главврач. Но есть главврач больницы, а есть главврач поликлиники или главврач госпиталя. Экс главврач больницы, если перешёл на эту же должность в поликлинику, не будет экс-главврачом, он настоящий главврач, но в другой организации. А вот если его уволили и он перешёл на другую работу или в этой же больнице остался простым врачом, то он экс-главврач.

Министр обороны - слитное сочетание, термин, значит, экс относится ко всему сочетанию и писаться через дефис не может, иначе будет относиться только к слову "министр". Вот когда никаким министром не будет, тогда будет экс-министр.

Comment: В советских шахматных изданиях писали исключительно экс-чемпион мира.

Comment: @МаркИз - и не только в шахматных. В любых. Другое никому в голову не приходило. Даже  если он потом стал чемпионом мира по преферансу, по шахматам он все равно экс-чемпион. То же и с министрами.

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, что существуют **слова  с иноязычным формантом ЭКС и дефисным его написанием: экс-министр, экс-чемпион, экс-главврач** и т.д., которые имеют значение бывший министр, чемпион, главврач.

Эти слова могут образовывать **"свободные" словосочетания** следующего вида:  экс-министр обороны, экс-чемпион мира по шахматам, экс-главврач больницы NN.

Экс-главврач больницы NN - это бывший главврач **этой конкретной больниц**ы, ни о каких других больницах речи нет.

Раздельное написания вида "экс министр обороны" по значению не отличается от "экс-министра обороны", искать здесь какое-то особое содержание не имеет смысла.

Comment: *Экс-главврач больницы NN - это бывший главврач этой конкретной больницы, ни о каких других больницах речи нет.* - а может кому-то прийти в голову контекст, где требовалось бы иное? Если да, то подобные дифференцирующие написания имеют смысл. Но я что-то крепко сомневаюсь. Не сочтите за критику,просто хочется убедиться, что мы на одном языке говорим.

Comment: Если специалист в данный момент работает в другом месте, то там он имеет новую должность, например: Иванов,  экс-главврач больницы  N1,  перешел работать в министерство или назначен на должность главврача больницы N2.

Comment: Sibylla, если ***"экс министр обороны"*** по значению не отличается от ***"экс-министра обороны"*** не отличается, тогда вообще вы видите какую-нибудь разницу между этими двумя случаями?

Comment: *Если специалист в...* - я не понял вашего ответа. Совсем. Да, вот ушел человек с этой должности в больнице. Какая тут может быть двусмысленность или необходимость что-то уточнять? Если он остался в тойже больнице или перешел на аналогичную должность в другой больнице и это важно говорящему, он так и скажет.

Comment: Не, я смысловой разницы не вижу, вся разница смысла или необходимость различения ситуаций состоит в указании конкретной больницы. Человек может быть главврачом в новой больнице, но при этом он остаётся экс-главврачом старой больницы.  Единственный вариант: его сначала сняли с должности, а потом вернули на эту же должность в той же больнице - тогда он уже не экс-главврач, а просто главврач. Должность Министра обороны  РФ человек занимает в течение какого-то времени, в дальнейшем он всегда будет экс-министром обороны, если только опять не займет эту должность.

Comment: Sibylla, так в чем теперь разница между этими двумя вариантами?

Comment: Нет разницы: только один смысл, который  во всех возможных ситуациях успешно предает дефисная форма написания.